# Is there way to wrap results in Select2 in additional markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have been using Select2 for my projects with great success.

I would like to know if anyone has idea of the best approach for significant modification of the markup in dropdown.

For example I would like to add an input field and a button at the bottom of the results.

[image: screenshot]

Does it seem like a feasible task for select2? Or is it a wrong tool for that? Currently I am using plugin that was developed in house but it is not really reliable and slow.

Comment: What is the purpose of the textbox?  Is for filtering or collecting additional information?

Comment: "Select a Course" is for filtering and it is the actual `select` field

Comment: "Enter your course number" is for adding an item to the list of choices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On option:

```
<style>
#s2id_test
{
    width: 200px;
}
.addedDiv
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.addedDiv input
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
}
.addedDiv button
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
}
</style>



<body>
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="4">Test 4</option>
    <option value="5">Test 5</option>
</select>
<script>
(function ($) {

/**
* @function
* @property {object} jQuery plugin which runs handler function once specified element is inserted into the DOM
* @param {function} handler A function to execute at the time when the element is inserted
* @param {bool} shouldRunHandlerOnce Optional: if true, handler is unbound after its first invocation
* @example $(selector).waitUntilExists(function);
* https://gist.github.com/buu700/4200601
*/

$.fn.waitUntilExists    = function (handler, shouldRunHandlerOnce, isChild) {
    var found       = 'found';
    var $this       = $(this.selector);
    var $elements   = $this.not(function () { return $(this).data(found); }).each(handler).data(found, true);

    if (!isChild)
    {
        (window.waitUntilExists_Intervals = window.waitUntilExists_Intervals || {})[this.selector] =
            window.setInterval(function () { $this.waitUntilExists(handler, shouldRunHandlerOnce, true); }, 100)
        ;
    }
    else if (shouldRunHandlerOnce && $elements.length)
    {
        window.clearInterval(window.waitUntilExists_Intervals[this.selector]);
    }

    return $this;
}

}(jQuery));
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').select2();

    $('#test').on("open", function() {
        if (!$('.addedDiv',$('.select2-drop-active')).is('*'))
        {
           $('.select2-drop-active').waitUntilExists(function(){$('.select2-drop-active').append('<div class="addedDiv"><input type="text"><button onclick="add(this)">Add</button></div>')});
        }
    });
 });
 function add(btn)
 {
    if($(btn).prev().is('input'))
    {
        $('#test').append('<option value="'+$($(btn).prev()).val()+'">'+$($(btn).prev()).val()+'</option>');
        $('#test').select2('close');
        $('#test').select2('open');
    }
 }
</script>
```

Tested win32 width:  chrome, firefox, IE